# How get correct values from DB in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm begginer in Laravel. I have this code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use psCMS\Presenters\UserPresenter;

    public static $roles = [];


    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
    }


    public function hasRole(array $roles)
    {

        foreach($roles as $role)
        {

            if(isset(self::$roles[$role]))
            {
                if(self::$roles[$role])  return true;

            }
            else
            {
                self::$roles[$role] = $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
                if(self::$roles[$role]) return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

and schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('counter')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });


Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });



Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });
```

And my user:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'Marian',
            'surname' => 'La',
            'email' => 'marian@icloud.com',
            'email_verified_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            'password' => Hash::make('passw'),
        ]);       

DB::table('role_user')->insert([
                'user_id' => 1,
                'role_id' => 1,
            ]);
```

This code work fine. I have problem with my role.
How can i print user role in blade?

I make this code:

```
public function getAdmin(int $id)
    {
        return User::find($id);
    }

$admin = $this->getAdmin(1);
```

And now my $admin - has admin object.

When i print in blade file: $admin->name, $admin->surname - it's work.

When i print: {{ $admin->roles }}

i have result:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"admin","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]
```

How can I show correct value (admin):

**I need result: admin not this:
    [{"id":1,"name":"admin","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **Many to Many** relationship and each user may have many roles ! So use `foreach` to print all of rules in your **blade** :

```
@foreach ($admin->roles as $role)
  {{ $role -> name }},
@endforeach
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Hope this helps !